# Use asl_log for logging only to a log file

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, logging

I'd like to define new asl facility in my project, to prevent my asl log message from showing up in /var/log/system.log

here's my entire asl configuration :

--> my facility is com.bla.bla

--> configuraiton file /etc/asl/com.bla.bla

```
> bla.log rotate=utc ttl=7 compress file_max=5M all_max=25M mode=0640 
format=$((Time)(local.6))\ $(Host)\ $(USERNAME)\ $(Sender)[$(PID):$(TID)]\ 
:\ $(Message)
? [= Facility com.bla.bla] [<= Level info] file bla.log
```

--> aslclient and aslmsg creation :

(notice that in asl_client, ASL_OPT_STDERR flag is unset)

```
asl_client = asl_open(name, "com.bla.bla", 0); 
asl_msg = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
```

--> asl message calls

```
asl_log(asl_client, asl_msg, log_level , message_format);
```

However, I still see those messages arriving to /var/log/system.log, although i haven't specified it anywhere in my configuration, and meant them to go to bla.log only.

Any idea what have I missed here ?

EDIT : Just found out that the reason for my logging finding their way to  system.log is the following section in asl.conf file. Notice that according to the second rule, all messages (disregarding facility) that are above or including level notice, will be route to system.log.

I wish to overrun this rule for my specific facility in it's dedicated conf file. is it possible ?

```
# Rules for /var/log/system.log 
> system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [= Sender kernel] file system.log
? [<= Level notice] file system.log
? [= Facility auth] [<= Level info] file system.log
? [= Facility authpriv] [<= Level info] file system.log
```

Comment: Looks more like an administration problem than a programming.

Comment: @Olaf, I believe it's not merely administration issue, since asl activation and usage is implemented inside the code.

Comment: Log configuration should be system-side. Anyway, welcome to prove me wrong.